# AppVeyor deploy to AppHarbor

Tags: deployment, continuous-integration, appharbor, appveyor

I would like to build my application in AppVeyor and then deploy it to AppHarbor.

I'm guessing there's a way to get AppVeyor to push the built code to the AppHarbor Repository URL but I can't figure out how to do it.

Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to get this working by doing the following:

I went to AppVeyor -> Encrypt Data and encrypted my AppHarbor username and password.

Added an appveyor.yml file to my GitHub repo:

```
environment:
username:
    secure: <Encrypted Username>
password:
    secure: <Encrypted Password>

on_success:
  - git config --global credential.helper store
  - ps: Add-Content "$env:USERPROFILE\.git-credentials" "https://$($env:username):$env:password@appharbor.com`n"
  - git remote add appharbor <AppHarbor Repository Url>
  - git push appharbor master
```

Once I confirmed this was working I went to Service Hooks in AppHarbor and deleted the GitHub one. And also removed hook on GitHub side.

In my case I am doing this because I want to run my tests in AppVeyor but not in AppHarbor. I managed this by disabling my test project from building in Release mode. But this could also be achieved with an AppHarbor.sln file.

Comment: How does this work exactly tho? Are you pushing your code to a new repo which is bound to the appharbor site? Why then did you remove the github hook?